# SpringBoot- logback.xml read from application-Environment.properties

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I am using a spring boot application. I deploy my code to three different envrionments(local,dev,int). Currently the logback.xml reads from application.properties. How do I make it to read from application-dev.properties, application-int.properties.. depending on the environment that the application has been deployed?

Comment: see spring doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you will deploy the app. For example, if you are deploying it on a server, you can start the spring boot app via an external configuration like here -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Or, if you are trying to do this locally, say on IntelliJ, you can create a new configuration and override the spring boot parameters as you want -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#d687672e16

If you are using eclipse (STS) -> https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4

Even better is to create multiple properties (or yaml) files, something like application-dev.properties, application-int.properties etc. and when you start the app, set the profile as "dev" or "int" or whatever you need -> http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: thanks, the way I went ahead was to have those necessary values  in the environment variables. It looks like Spring boot logback first looks at env variables then at the application property files.                                                   So, for each env I will have environment var based on that env.

Comment: Sure, I missed that, yeah, environment variables works great as well.